# How many goldfish can I put into a 55 gallon (210 liters) fish tank?

Tags: fish, goldfish

I have a 55 gallon (210 liters) fish tank and I have goldfish in there right now. I'm just setting it up, it's been two months. I'm putting a lot of live plants in it.

How many goldfish can I put in there, what's the limit?

Comment: I have 10  small feeders goldfish in there now was wondering if I could put any more different colored ones but what's the limit that they'll be comfortable

Comment: Feeders are comet goldfish. They definitely need a lot of space. I would caution 20 gallons isn't near enough for mature ones, they probably would do better with more like 50 gallons for the 1st and 30 for each subsequent for mature comets, and that's the absolutely minimum, a pond would be even better... You'd be better off with fancy goldfish which do not get as large and do not have anywhere close to the high energy level and metabolism as comets.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that a common consensus from most goldfish-themed websites is 20 gallons (76 liters) for the first goldfish, and then 10 gallons (38 liters) more for each additional one beyond that... so in your case, 4 fish would be good.